# Conversion of an sql query to sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I am trying to convert this sql query to sequelize. The sequelize query should have the same result as the sql query.

```
SELECT * FROM logs 
    WHERE createdAt >= '2020-06-24 00:00:00' 
        AND createdAt <= '2020-06-26 23:59:59'
        AND targetId = 192
        AND `type` = 1
```

#My current implementation

```
query = {
        [Op.and]: [
          { createdAt: { [Op.gte]: startDate } },
          { createdAt: { [Op.lte]: endDate } },
          { targetId: userId },
          { type: 1 },
        ],
      };
```

Comment: Have a look here  https://fengmk2.github.io/blog/2014/10/sql-to-sequelize-mapping-chart.html

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi can you post your answer Sir ?

Answer (score 1):

To make a query like yours, you need something like the following:

```
{
    where: {
        createdAt: {
          [Op.gte]: startDate,
          [Op.lte]: endDate
        },
        targetId: userId,
        type: 1
    }
}
```

[More details in the documentation.](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)

Comment: But I am using o.p sequelize , do you think Sir  [Op.and] is no longer Needed.

Comment: No, in this case it is not needed.